# Can't execute a bash script in a docker container in a jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm been learning how to use Jenkins and test different things, now I'm testing build a Django project with docker in my windows machine, just for experimenting and learning purpose, in the project I have a SH file called entrypoint.sh for cleaning my DB and then run migrations for testing build, the first step of the first stage of my Jenkins pipeline is a docker-compose command for building the development version of the project, but when my Dockerfile executes the entrypoint step it says that the entrypoint.sh file is no such a file or directory, when I execute manually the docker-compose file it works fine, I try other angle, I take off that step and try to put a step in the Jenkinsfile to execute with docker-compose exec a ls command in the container to see if for some reason is not in there, and there is, when I do manually in a terminal a docker-compose exec command for executing that file, the entrypoint.sh file, there is not a problem, but if a put that step in the Jenkinsfile, it says the same, I put another step that executes a python script and works, but the entrypoint.sh doesn't work, so I don't know if is not allow to execute bash scripts in a step of Jenkins pipeline, but if someone could help me I would appreciate it very much.

This is the simple pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any


    stages{
        stage('build test'){
            steps {
                
                powershell '''
                    docker-compose -f Simple_Store_D/Simple-Store.dev.yml up -d --build
                    docker-compose -f Simple_Store_D/Simple-Store.dev.yml exec simple-store ls
                    docker-compose -f Simple_Store_D/Simple-Store.dev.yml exec simple-store /home/src/entrypoint.sh
                    docker-compose -f Simple_Store_D/Simple-Store.dev.yml exec simple-store python manage.py test
                    docker-compose -f Simple_Store_D/Simple-Store.dev.yml down 
                '''
                
            }
        }
    }
}

#This is the Dockerfile

FROM python:3

WORKDIR /home/src 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional

COPY requirements.txt ./ 

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

COPY ./entrypoint.sh . 

RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /home/src/entrypoint.sh 
RUN chmod +x /home/src/entrypoint.sh 

COPY . .

# I commented the entrypoint because it says can't find the file
# ENTRYPOINT ["/home/src/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I see if there was a problem doing it manually, executing the commands in a terminal and it works fine, and it suppose to execute in powershell without a problem the commands I execute manually, so I don't know what else to do, and sorry if I'm no so clear about what I'm asking about or if I sound silly.